# Referencing a list in a function or class with PHP

Tags: php, arrays, list, function, class

thanks in advance for any help. I am new to using classes & functions with php so i'm not quite sure how to go about doing this. I have a list that forms an array and I want to reference it across multiple classes / functions without having to call the list every time. Here is the code I have been working with. How can I put the list & array in a global format that I can use to reference the list in other classes & functions?

```
class article {


public static function data(){

        list($articles, $articlesMetaData) = getRecords(array(
    'tableName'   => 'articles',
    'where'       => whereRecordNumberInUrl(0),
    'loadUploads' => true,
    'allowSearch' => false,
    'loadCreatedBy'      => true,
    'limit'       => '1',
  ));
  $article = @$articles[0]; // get first record
  if (!$articles) { dieWith404("Record not found!"); } // show error message if no record found

     echo $article['article'];

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use list and article as global var you just have to declare them in the body of your code and declare it in your function as global.

```
<?php
    $article  = null;

    public static function data()
    {
        global $article;
        $article = ...;

$b = $a + $b;
```

}

Comment: I need to reference values from the list in other classes & functions because some of my variables are referencing data from the list. For example in list I have a string $article['num'] that is used in a variable called $articleNum i'd like to just reference $articleNum in other classes without calling the entire list

Comment: To be more clear, it's the list I want to reference in other classes & functions. I already know how to pull variables into other classes & functions

Comment: Thanks Sascha! Your answer was what I needed I just needed to reorder some things and think about it more, thanks again you rock!

Comment: @MatrixHyperLoop Forget about the global keyword, if you really want to use oop. If you need to use this keyword in the oop paradigm, there is always something wrong